# Google analytics - gtag user id issues

Tags: google-analytics

I've been trying to send user_id to google analytics with no success so far. I followed the instructions on the console which is basically to set the 'user_id' as follows:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XXX"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }

    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'XXXXX', {'user_id': '{{ user.id }}'});
</script>
```

Most of the thread i've read was to configure in the old way: `ga`

Answer (score 6):

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cookies-user-id#set_user_id) , you should be setting it like so:

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {
  'user_id': 'USER_ID'
});
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that yesterday, but nothing appears in the User Explorer view

Comment: You have it enabled for your view?

Comment: Yes, I’ve followed the instructions in GA which is a nice interface with a next next. I’ve added this script in the head section of my html and I’m importing gtag only.

Comment: I just asked here too: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Code/Google-analytics-User-ID-data-not-showing-data/td-p/1861649

Comment: Mystery solved. Everything was correctly configured, it took 2 days to show data on the view.